# Using Sympy on methods from the math module

Tags: python, lambda, sympy

As part of a wider plotting program I have a script where there is a function `f` defined as a lambda expression, and I need to find its derivative. My code for testing the script is:

```
import math 
import sympy as sym

f = lambda x : math.sin(x) 

sx = sym.symbols('x')

sf = sym.diff(f(sx), sx) 
print(sf)
```

While this works fine when `f` is defined without using any outside methods, the above throws `TypeError: can't convert expression to float` because the math module's methods don't support the symbolic representations used by Sympy. However, while this works when `f` instead uses `sym.sin`, because of how the aforementioned program is structured the definition of `f` cannot be changed. Is there a way to symbolically interpret the math module's methods?

Comment: My only idea would be to execute "f(x)" inside of an "eval" where the global namespace contains a faked "math" module which consists of the sympy functions. This may even need more hackish trickery to work.

Comment: Why would you want/need to do that? Smells like XY problem...

Comment: sympy doesn't work on methods from the math module.  `import inspect; inspect.getsource(f)`  maybe could help to automatically replace  math function with sympy functions, provided the functions are extremely simple.  In general, however, this won't work.

Comment: Have you tried using `sympy.sin` instead of `math.sin`? For instance, `x = sympy.symbols('x'); print(sympy.diff(sympy.sin(x), x))` correctly prints `cos(x)`.